# PHP7 FPM and Nginx - Getting 404s

Tags: php, nginx

This is my sites-available/myServer, correctly linked to sites-enabled/myServer:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sub.domain.net;

    location / {
             root /home/tyrion/saveup-compute;
             index index.php index.html index.htm
             try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
         root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/username/myServer/$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

I went into php fpm file and set 660 and www-data and set chown in my directory to www-data:myuser. Still, I can't serve a single php file. (html works just fine).

Nginx Access Log:

```
MYIP - - [15/Sep/2016:23:09:13 +0000] "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36"
```

Nginx Error Log:

```
2016/09/15 23:09:13 [error] 38415#38415: *2 open() "/home/myUser/myServer/404.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 62.155.132.7, server: sub.somain.net, request: "GET /info.php HTTP/1.1", host: "sub.somain.net"
```

php7.0-fpm.log:

```
[15-Sep-2016 21:54:49] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 35917
[15-Sep-2016 21:54:49] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[15-Sep-2016 21:54:49] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
[15-Sep-2016 22:56:58] NOTICE: Terminating ...
[15-Sep-2016 22:56:58] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[15-Sep-2016 22:56:58] NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful

[15-Sep-2016 22:56:58] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 37925
[15-Sep-2016 22:56:58] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[15-Sep-2016 22:56:58] NOTICE: systemd monitor interval set to 10000ms
```

Comment: should your try be `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;` or something along those lines

Comment: Are you sure your files are located at `/home/tyrion/saveup-compute`? Are you using any sort of `mod_rewrite` routing?

Comment: No mod_rewrite but maybe I should consider it.

Comment: Your nginx error says the host is `somain.net` and your conf is looking for `domain.net`

Comment: @Blake I obfuscated my domain. Its just a typo in above logs.

Comment: @Perspective Would gives cyclic dependency.

Comment: Where exactly is the docroot for this site? And is there an `info.php` in that docroot?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123492/discussion-between-stephan-kristyn-and-blake).

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be two problems here.

First problem is the lack of a `root` directive for the `location ~ \.php$` block means that the `try_files $uri =404;` statement will always fail with a 404 response.

The 404 response is redirected to `/404.html` and from the error log, it seems that there is no file called `/home/tyrion/saveup-compute/404.html`.

If you are placing your HTML files and PHP files in different directory hierarchies, then you need to add a `root` directive to the `location ~ \.php$` block, so that the `try_files` directive will work.

If you are placing your HTML files and PHP files in the same directory hierarchy, then you should move the `root /home/tyrion/saveup-compute;` statement into the `server` block, so that the same value is inherited by all of your `location` blocks.

You should also change the definition of `SCRIPT_FILENAME` so that it uses the correct `root` value (include fastcgi_params first to avoid it silently overwriting your definitions):

```
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) for more.